# Putting hypertext link to external internet site inside javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I want my javadoc to reference a dev manual that is on my intranet. I would like to know how to do this: I tried using see {@link http://json.org} but this just produced http://json.org and not a hypertext link. Let's say I wanted to point to some wiki page inside the javadoc. How can I do this? I am just trying to have link to external website. So I want something like Example as hypertext link and it points to a full URL to website.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question does not answer how to use `{@link }` with URLs. The answer, that it won't work, does not appear at all in the other question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`{@link}` and `{@linkplain}` are specifically used to link to other javadoc.

To link to a plain web page you can simply use an HTML link:

```
* @see <a href="http://json.org/">The JSON site</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/**
* some text <a href="https://www.example1.com">some in text link</a>
* @see <a href="https://www.example2.com">some other link</a>
*/
public void someFunction() {}
```

will be displayed as

> `public void someFunction()`
>
> some text [some in text link](https://www.example1.com)
>
> **See also:**
> [some other link](https://www.example2.com)